# How to get user details from an Azure AD token?

Tags: azure, web, .net-core, token

Using this tutorial as a guide: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa-aspnetcore-webapi

In the web api we need to obtain the users details (for audit purposes we want to record the details of the user in the database).

In the web api, is there a way to decode the azure token to obtain the user details? Or we could simply pass the user email from the client browser in each request also be feasible (this is easily accessible using the MSAL library for Angular)

Answer (score 1):

You could decode token to get some information of the signed-in user such as username and email, try token with https://jwt.io/.

If you want more details, you can use [MS Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). `Me` means current signed-in user. Try with following Graph SDK or [HttpClient sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/master/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs#L133).

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

// or graphClient.Users[user-object-id].Request().GetAsync(); for a specific user
var user = await graphClient.Me
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but as suggested in my answer, using the User property from the base controller provided what I need

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to decode the token to get the current users email, the base controller exposes the current user as detailed here;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/claimsprincipal-current?view=aspnetcore-2.1

So simply using the following I can obtain the user associated with the current request;

```
string email = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
```